# OpenERP - How to add decimal precision on current rate curreny

Tags: odoo, currency

I want to add decimal precision on current rate currency openERP 7.
I've already installed "decimal precision currency" addon, but when try to set decimal curracy into 12 digits, just only rounding factor that changed that become 12 digits and the current rate still 6 digit.

How can I modify the current rate into 12 digits?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I research in your problem i get a solution for you. **current rate** is a function field and it's digits(12, 6) means 12 significant digits and 6 decimal points. If you want to check that file than go to **server/openerp/addons/base/res/res_currency.py**. And find **current rate** and change this filed with this below. And you will get 12 decimal points in your **current rate**.

```
'rate_silent': fields.function(_current_rate_silent, string='Current Rate', digits=(12,12),
 help='The rate of the currency to the currency of rate 1 (0 if no rate defined).'),
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: most welcome, if your problem is solve than give upvote and accept the answer. So others will know that this question is done. Thanks..

Comment: ok, thanks for your advice. I dont know about the vote before because Im still new in this forum. Thanks

Comment: as where you accept the answer, see the upper part UP and DOWN arrow is their, that means upvote and downvote. Why you first take a tour of Stackoverflow. It's easy to use. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go into 'Settings -> In Configuration Tab - Invoice'

There set your decimal precision to 12. If you cant or without effects then tip off 'This company has own chart account' and 'Apply'. Set decimal precision to your needs. Below you will find default currency. Also in currency change precision to 12.